# Deleted music off phone from computer with space no change

Tags: internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory

I was already out of space on my phone and wanted new music on it so I deleted 140MB of songs off my phone through the computer window(phone was usb hooked up to computer). So I go ahead to transfer my new music onto the phone by computer when It tells me I have no space.... the phones properties on the computer is showing up as if theres been no change in space.
Since then I've cleared all my cashes, tryied downloading a phone cleaner app but the phones saying not enough space for that either. Yet when I go through the phones settings to check up its storage. it says I have over 500 MB Free!...

if it matters I'm using a cheap ZTE phone Model: Z798BL